# Increment cell reference by 1 every 6th row

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, format, auto-increment

I need A1 to increment by 1 to A2 after 5 rows, and then to A3 after a further 5 rows etc.

What I need:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&SheetList!$A1&"'!D3")
=INDIRECT("'"&SheetList!$A1&"'!D3")
=INDIRECT("'"&SheetList!$A1&"'!D3")
=INDIRECT("'"&SheetList!$A1&"'!D3")
=INDIRECT("'"&SheetList!$A1&"'!D3")
=INDIRECT("'"&SheetList!$A2&"'!D3")
=INDIRECT("'"&SheetList!$A2&"'!D3")
=INDIRECT("'"&SheetList!$A2&"'!D3")
=INDIRECT("'"&SheetList!$A2&"'!D3")
=INDIRECT("'"&SheetList!$A2&"'!D3")
```

But this is happening:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&SheetList!$A1&"'!D3")
=INDIRECT("'"&SheetList!$A2&"'!D3")
=INDIRECT("'"&SheetList!$A3&"'!D3")
```

Even when I specify multiple A1's and drag it down, it still messes up.

Answer (score 2):

See below example:

Formula for C1:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&FLOOR((ROW()-1)/5,1)+1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi there and thanks for your help. How would I keep this part: of my INDIRECT formula: "'"&SheetList!$A1&"'!D3") to make it look in my sheet SheetList, find the sheet name (listed in column A) and reference the sheet name specified at the A position at D3? The only change being that I have it look in the same sheet for 5 rows before increment from A1 to A2, to A3 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with `INDIRECT` you may be able to use excels auto increment, but divide it by 6, followed by a `CEIL`. If that doesn't work you can get the `ROW` of the current cell and substract it by the `ROW` of the first row in your sequence.

I have a german version of Excel and the functions are all translated, so you might need to check the names.

Comment: I'm not actually too sure how I'd implement those to change the A1 value to A2 after 5 rows ie how do you add that to my formula without removing its functionality?

Answer (score 1):

`=INDIRECT("'"&INDEX(SheetList!$A:$A,CEILING(ROWS($1:1)/5,1))&"'!D3")`

ROWS is preferable to ROW in this sort of construction, as is INDEX to INDIRECT.

Regards